# Solving exponential equation with two variables

Tags: calculus

Given are two equations:

$$v_1 = v_0 (1 - e^{-\frac{t_1}{\tau}})$$

$$v_2 = v_0 (1 - e^{-\frac{t_2}{\tau}})$$

We know that

$$t_2 > t_1$$
$$v_2 > v_1$$
$$\tau > 0$$
$$v_0 > 0$$
$$\tau, v_0 \in ℝ$$

Given $t_1, v_1, t_2, v_2$, how can we solve for $\tau, v_0$?

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick :-( I forgot the (1-exp()) in the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p:=e^{-t_1/\tau}$ so that $e^{-t_2/\tau}=p^\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is known. The equation can be written

$$v_1(1-p^\alpha)=v_2(1-p).$$

$\alpha$ can be an integer $>4$ so that there are certainly cases such that there is no closed-form solution. (In fact, there are only closed-form solutions for a few rational values of $\alpha$.)

Comment: i thought $\tau$ is not known?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: indeed, it is an unknown. What is the problem ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I must admit that I am having trouble to follow. Could you maybe elaborate on how to proceed with finding $\tau$ after the substitution you describe has been performed? I'm staring at the equation but cannot figure it our right now, I apologize.

Comment: The point is that in general there's no analytical solution ;-)

Comment: $\alpha = \frac{t_2}{t_1}$, so you have some polynomial-looking equation of $p$ which is $v_1(1-p^{\alpha})-v_2(1-p) = 0$. In general, we may not be able to find $p\neq1$ analytically, but if we could get $p$, then we can find $\tau = -\frac{t_1}{\log(p)}$, and $v_0 = \frac{v_1}{1-p}$.

Comment: Ah, okay! Wow, surprising but I believe it. At least I wasn't too stupid to figure out the solution :-) Thank you for the clarification.